# How to define Entity bean field in java for unique key defined in DB2 as TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Tags: java, jpa, sql-timestamp

I'm trying to figure out how to write the Entity bean for a table with a unique issue... specifically how to deal with the unique key being a TIMESTAMP column. I want to let the DB create the value using its DEFAULT clause.

I've tried adding `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` to the field definition, changing it from

```
@Id
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ROW_ADD_TS",
        columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP",
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false)
protected Timestamp rowAddDateTime; // WAS org.joda.time.DateTime
```

to

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ROW_ADD_TS",
        columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP",
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false)
protected Timestamp rowAddDateTime; // WAS org.joda.time.DateTime
```

And commenting out any code that sets `rowAddDateTime` to a value other than null.  I've also tried other `GenerationType` values... all to no avail.

Here's the DB2 version of the table definition and the only unique index actually defined on the server.

```
CREATE TABLE X.LOGS
    (
        APP_NAM_TX CHARACTER(30) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL, 
        LOC_ID CHARACTER(3) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL,
        BIL_DIV_ID SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
        USR_NAM_TX CHARACTER(20) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL,
        FRM_NAM_TX CHARACTER(30) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL, 
        ROW_ADD_TS TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
        ACN_CD CHARACTER(2) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL, 
        ACN_DTL_TX VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, 
        DRN_AM DECIMAL(7, 2) DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL, 
        ADL_DRN_AM DECIMAL(7, 2) DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL, 
        RCD_CNT_QY INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
        QRY_CNT_QY SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 
        USR_NAM_DTL_TX CHARACTER(60), 
        DAB_NAM_ID SMALLINT DEFAULT 0
    );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX X.LOGS_1IX ON X.LOGS
    (
        ROW_ADD_TS, APP_NAM_TX, LOC_ID, BIL_DIV_ID, USR_NAM_TX, FRM_NAM_TX
    )   ALLOW REVERSE SCANS;
```

Comment: You can use '@PrePersist' and '@PreUpdate' to set the value before letting jpa generating the sql.

Comment: Not sure how that helps.  My whole goal here is to let the database assign the timestamp value since it has a higher timer resolution than Java.  Is there anything I could do in one of those routines to prevent JPA from generating INSERT SQL with a value for the ROW_ADD_TS?  It shouldn't even be in the insert statement.

Comment: Eventually, I gave up on JPA and used the JdbcTemplate to write my own SQL Insert statement, omitting the timestamp from the field list.